# Node.js "Cannot set headers after they are sent" error message

Tags: node.js

I read many questions on StackOverflow about this, but I couldn't find how can I solve this problem.

Here is my code.

```
// express 모듈을 가져와서 application 객체 생성
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// body-parser 모듈을 가져온다.
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// 미들웨어의 역할을 하는 bodyParser를 통해 POST방식으로 전달된 데이터를 접근할 수 있도록
// request 객체의 body 객체를 생성한다.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

// 파일시스템 모듈을 가져온다.
var fs = require('fs');

// template engine 폴더 설정, 사용하는 engine은 jade
app.set('views','./views_file');
app.set('view engine','jade');

// jade로 나타내어지는 html 코드를 이쁘게 보이도록 하는 것.
app.locals.pretty = true;

// 사용자의 특정 url 입력에 대한 response로 new.jade를 rendering 시킨다.
app.get('/topic/new',function(req,res){
    res.render('new');
})

// POST 방식으로 전달된 데이터를 data 폴더에 파일로 저장
app.post('/topic', function(req,res){
    var title = req.body.title;
    var description = req.body.description;
    fs.writeFile('/data'+title,description,function(err){
        if(err){ res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');}
        res.send('Success!');
    })
})

// 3000번 포트를 listening하고 있게 하는 것.
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('Connected, 3000 port!');
})
```

Sorry for my korean comments.

The error message is:

> Cannot set headers after they are sent.

This error occurs when I catch POST data from /topic/new.

How can I solve it?

Comment: instead of `res.status` and `res.send` do `return res.status` and `return res.send`

Comment: It was solved. But why I have to use 'return'?

Comment: I would remove all the Korean comments when posting the question to make the code easier to read, but that's just me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to stop the execution of your function if there is any error. The `return` statement tells the interpreter to stop execution and return control immediately to the handler. But, also, keep in mind that if a certain part of the function is the last one being called you don't necessarily need to put `return` before it. So your function can be written as -

```
app.post('/topic', function(req,res){
  var title = req.body.title;
  var description = req.body.description;
  fs.writeFile('/data'+title,description,function(err){
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }

    res.send('Success!');
  });
});
```

Comment: I understand what u said. But this error occurs only when I use 'post' method. 'get' method doesn't occur like this error about exception handling what u explained. Can u tell me why?