# Login system wrong username error handling with MySql / NodeJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, authentication

I have the below controller which I use to manage the login system on my app. Is working in all cases except the one when I insert the wrong username.

I have inserted the below conditional statement to handle the error:

```
 if (error === null) {
                res.status(401).render('login', {
                    message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
                })
            }
```

But when I insert it, I receive the following message on the terminal:

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

var db_config = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME
};

var connection;



function handleDisconnect() {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); // Recreate the connection, since
    // the old one cannot be reused.

    connection.connect(function (err) {              // The server is either down
        if (err) {                                     // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
            console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
            setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
        }                                     // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
    });                                     // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
    // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
    connection.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('db error', err);
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
            handleDisconnect();                         // lost due to either server restart, or a
        } else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
            throw err;                                  // server variable configures this)
        }
    });
}

handleDisconnect();





// code in case the user leave the login space empty

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        if (!email || !password) {
            return res.status(400).render('login', {
                message: 'Please provide an email and password'
            })
        }

        connection.query('SELECT * FROM login WHERE email=?', [email], async (error, results) => {
        
            // conditional statement to handle the wrong username error
            if (error === null) {
                res.status(401).render('login', {
                    message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
                })
            }
            //conditional if statement to compare password in database and password inserted by the client
            if (!results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password))) {
                res.status(401).render('login', {
                    message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
                }) //conditional statement to fetch the id of the client and signign in with sign() function
            } else {
                const id = results[0].id;
                const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
                });

                // console.log('the token is:' + token);
                const cookieOptions = {
                    expires: new Date(
                        Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 24 hours converted in milliseconds to set the expiration cookies to 24 hours
                    ),
                    httpOnly: true
                }//setting of cookies on the browser and redirecting to the user interface page
                res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
                res.status(200).redirect('/ui');
            }

        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("this is the error:", error)
    }

}


exports.register = (req, res) => {

 
    // Destructor
    const { name, email, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;
    //query that order to MySQL to get the user email only once
    connection.query('SELECT email FROM login WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        if (results.length > 0) {
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'That email is already in use'
            })
        } else if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'Password do not match'
            });
        }

        let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
        // console.log(hashedPassword);

        connection.query('INSERT INTO login SET ?', { name: name, email: email, password: hashedPassword }, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                // console.log(results);
                return res.render('register', {
                    message: 'User registered'
                });

            }
        })

    });

}


exports.isLoggedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
    // console.log(req.cookies);
    if (req.cookies.jwt) {
        try {
            //1)verify the token
            decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(req.cookies.jwt,
                process.env.JWT_SECRET
            );



            //2) Check if the user still exists
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM login WHERE id = ?', [decoded.id], (error, result) => {
                // console.log(result);

                if (!result) {
                    return next();
                }
                req.user = result[0];
                return next();
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

exports.logout = async (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('jwt');
    res.status(200).redirect('/');
}
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions or correction to the right path.

Comment: the are secure passwpord hasing function and verify that are secure. why not use them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js "Cannot set headers after they are sent" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081228/node-js-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-error-message)

Comment: I'm looking into both answers...

Comment: No, the above, is not answering my question unfortunately, If I insert return, even with username and pw correct I receive the message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, or at least is working. I deleted the first `if` statement and modify the remain one as below. instead of `!results` I edited it to `results == ""` . So if results is empty it will render the `login` with te alert `message`.

```js
if (results == "" || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password))) {
                res.status(401).render('login', {
                    message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
                }) //conditio
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to return the response or the function will continue.

```
return res.status(401).render('login', {
  message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to halt the execution of the function by putting the `return` keyword or the code will run through the other statements.

```
if (error === null) {
    return res.status(401).render('login', {
          message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
    })
}
```

Or

```
if (error === null) {
    res.status(401).render('login', {
          message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
    })
    return
}
```

Comment: I inserted return as indicated, and now even if the user id and password are inserted correctly I get the message 'Email or Password is incorrect', so is not working.

Comment: I think you need to check the returned length of `results` to determine whether the email address is available and not just checking on whether error is null. I would go with `if (error === null && results.length === 0)`.